# Copying files from remote to local using lftp in unix

Tags: ftp, unix, file-transfer

I'm trying to write a script to copy some files from a remote ftp server to a local directory. I have seen lots of examples using the mirror command of lftp but so far none of them seem to work. Currently I have a command that looks like this:

```
lftp -u myuser ftp.myserver.net -e 'set ftp:ssl-allow no;mirror -c --verbose eyerep-test/outgoing/archive ~/eyerep-files/outgoing;quit;'
```

If I execute that command, it will connect to the server and try to run the mirror command, but when it finishes I don't see any files copied into the /eyerep-files/outgoing folder on my machine. I also tried connecting to the remote with lftp and running the commands one at a time. I got the same results. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone shed some light on why this command isn't working?